# How to inherit from a base generic class

Tags: java

Have a base genric class like `ClassBase<T>`

I found I can use

```
ClassDerived extends ClassBase
```

or

```
ClassDerived<T> extends Classbase<T>
```

So basically it means I can remove generics in the derived class, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all generic type information is erased in the compilation process, of course you can do that. However, most compilers will generate a warning unless the warning is turned off or suppressed. For instance, if I write `class Foo extends HashMap {}`, Eclipse reports: "HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap should be parameterized"

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the raw version of a generic class, that's correct. Of course your second example:

```
ClassDerived<T> extends Classbase
```

... actually re-introduces a type parameter.